# $\frac{y}{x-z}=\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: fractions, ratio

If for three distinct positive numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$, $$\frac{y}{x-z}=\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{x}{y}$$

then find the value of $\frac{x}{y}$

I have tried all types of manipulations, even quadratics but can seem to get the answer. Please help!! BTW im a 7th grader so easy solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: @rsadhvika this is a no calculator question btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{(y)+(x+y)+(x)}{(x-z)+(z)+(y)}=\frac{2(x+y)}{x+y}=2$$
Explaination:
We shall prove that if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then, $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a+kc}{b+kd}$ (using $k=1$ for the above solution)

Since $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, then $\frac{d}{b}=\frac{c}{a}$  so...
$$\frac{a+kc}{b+kd}=\frac{a(1+k(c/a))}{b(1+k(d/b))}=\frac{a(1+k(c/a))}{b(1+k(c/a))}=\frac{a}{b}$$ (Try with some fractions if your not convinced Ex:$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1+2}{2+4}$

Thus, in the problem, we can say x/y is the sum of numerators over the sum of the denominators and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! this is a very fast way to get the answer thanks, I also learned something new

Answer (score 1):

Given:

$\frac{y}{x-z} = \frac{x+y}{z} = \frac{x}{y}$

Note that if

$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$

then each of them is equal to

$\frac{a\pm c}{b \pm d}$ provided $b \pm d \neq 0$

Using this property, from the first two fractions, we obtain

$\frac{x+2y}{x} = \frac{x}{y}$

Simplifying,

$x^2 = xy + 2y^2$

Put $x = ky$ in the above equation to obtain

$k^2 - k - 2 = 0$

Solving $k = 2, -1$

Since $k \neq -1$, we must have $k = 2$

Comment: May I ask were did the k come from

Comment: Actually I was editing... Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't understand your first step

Comment: Have you understood now?

Comment: ya the art of problem solving proved that in his/her answer above but thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let $\alpha=\frac{x}{y}$. Then 
$$\frac{y}{x-z}=\frac{x+y}{z}=\alpha \\
x=\alpha y$$
giving
$$\frac{(\alpha+1)y}{z}=\alpha \Rightarrow z=\frac{(\alpha+1)y}{\alpha} \\
\frac{y}{\alpha y- \frac{(\alpha+1)y}{\alpha}}=\alpha \Rightarrow \\1=\alpha \left( \alpha - \frac{(\alpha+1)}{\alpha}\right)\\$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider (first & third terms)
$$\frac{y}{x-z}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$z=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x}\tag1$$
Similarly, consider (second & third terms)
$$\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{x+y}{\frac{x^2-y^2}{x}}=\frac{x}{y}\quad (\text{setting the value of z from (1)})$$
$$\frac{x(x+y)}{(x+y)(x-y)}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{x}{x-y}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{x/y}{x/y-1}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2-2\frac{x}{y}=0$$
$$\frac xy\left(\frac{x}{y}-2\right)^2=0$$
$$\frac xy=0\ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac xy =2$$
But $x, y, z>0$ hence$$\frac xy =2$$

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution but thanks

Answer (score 0):

$z=\frac{y(x+y)}{x}$, $x(x-z)=y^2$, $x-z=\frac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x}$, $y^2=x^2-xy-y^2$, let $u=\frac{y}{x}$, $2u.^2+u-1=0$, $u=-1$, or $u=\frac{1}{2}$

Final result  $\frac{x}{y}=2$, since $x$ and $y$ have to be positive.

Comment: in the problem I said positive numbers so your first solution is wrong

Comment: Sorry - I missed that requirement.  I've edited my result.